# contentOffset Opposite Calculation

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button that changes colour on scrollOffset. I have the below code working except it is performing the animation in the opposite direction. Instead of it fading from transparent to opaque (0% - 100%) I want it to do the opposite (100% - 0%). I think I am calculating my offset wrong but am unsure what the correct way of calculating this is?

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // Offset is WRONG
    var offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y / 150

    if offset > 1 {
        offset = 1
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 1, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: offset)
    } else {
        buttomn.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 1, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: offset)
    }
}
```

Comment: try this    var offset = 1 - ( scrollView.contentOffset.y / 150)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @ReinierMelian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the check for greater than 1 can be replaced by `min()`:

```swift
offset = min(1, offset)
```

Since `contentOffset.y` could also be negative, you might want to prevent negative values using `max()`:

```swift
offset = max(0, min(1, offset))
```

Now, if you want to flip the direction, simply subtract that value from 1:

```swift
offset = 1 - max(0, min(1, offset))
```

Alternatively, do it in one line:

```
let offset = 1 - max(0, min(1, scrollView.contentOffset.y / 150))
```

Finally, set the color:

```
buttom.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 1, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: offset)
```